# Compute the linear transformation of a vector with respect to an ordered basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a homework problem whose process I can't seem to figure out; any help provided is much appreciated:

Let the representation of $L: R^3 -> R^2$ with respect to the ordered bases $S = {v_1, v_2, v_3}$ and $T = {w_1, w_2}$ be

$A=\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 & 1\\ -1 & 1 & 0\end{array}\right]$

where $v_1 = \left[\begin{array}{cc} -1\\1\\0\end{array}\right]$, $v_2 = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0\\1\\1\end{array}\right]$, $v_3 = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1\\0\\0\end{array}\right]$, $w_1 = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1\\2\end{array}\right]$, $w_2 = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1\\-1\end{array}\right]$

I have to compute $[L(v_1)]_T$ and $L(v_1)$.

What I tried to do was set up an augmented matrix with $A$ on the right and $I_n$ on the left but I don't know what to do from there. Should I then attempt to make the first two columns of the augmented matrix into $w_1$ and $w_2$?

Comment: first calculate L(v_1).

Comment: @TattwamasiAmrutam how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns of the matrix $A$ of the linear map $L$ w.r.t. the given bases are just the images $L(v_i)$ coordinated in $(w_1,w_2)$. That means exactly that
$$[L(v_1)]_T\ =\ \pmatrix{1\\-1},\quad  
[L(v_2)]_T\ =\ \pmatrix{2\\1},\quad
[L(v_3)]_T\ =\ \pmatrix{1\\0}\,.$$
In original coordinates, use $L(v_1)=1\cdot w_1+(-1)\cdot w_2$, moreover you might also express the standard basis with $v_i$'s, if you want to calculate the matrix of $L$ in the standard bases.

Answer (score 0):

$A=\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 & 1\\ -1 & 1 & 0\end{array}\right]$ is the matrix for linear transformation.
Hence $L(v_1)$= $Av_1$ which gives 
$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 & 1\\ -1 & 1 & 0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc} -1\\1\\0\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1\\2\end{array}\right]$ which is precisely $w_1$

Comment: I don't believe this is correct; 2 reasons: 1) I have a solution manual for this questions and $L(v_1)$ is given as [0, 3]; 2) I believe the given $A$ is representation of the linear operator with respect to S and T

Comment: Yes, my solution gives $L(v_1)=\pmatrix{0\\3}$ in the standard basis.